# Removing x-labels and confusion

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm quite new to LaTeX. I'm trying to figure out how to get rid of the x-value labels altogether (because I have the key).

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width  = 0.85*\textwidth,
    height = 8cm,
    major x tick style = transparent,
    ybar=2*\pgflinewidth,
    xticklabels=\empty,
    bar width=14pt,
    ymajorgrids = true,
    ylabel = {Percentage},
    xlabel = {},
    symbolic x coords={Doramus,Refaltido,Misanit,Fanatha,Sonphay,Laoli,Tidanme},
    scaled y ticks = false,
    enlarge x limits=2,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=100,
    legend cell align=left,
    legend style={
            at={(.872,.5)},
            anchor=south,
            column sep=1ex
    }  
]

\addplot[style={green,fill=green}]
    coordinates {(Doramus,60)};
\addplot[style={orange,fill=orange}]
    coordinates {(Refaltido,17)};
\addplot[style={yellow,fill=yellow}]
    coordinates {(Misanit,6)};
\addplot[style={blue,fill=blue}]
    coordinates {(Fanatha,6)};
\addplot[style={purple,fill=purple}]
    coordinates {(Sonphay,5)};
\addplot[style={black,fill=black}]
    coordinates {(Laoli,4)};
\addplot[style={black,fill=white}]
    coordinates {(Tidanme,2)};
\legend{Doramus,Refaltido,Misanit,Fanatha,Sonphay,Laoli,Tidanme}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Here is the image that turns out:

[image: Rendered graph]

I've already looked up the solution and tried doing `xlabel = {}` and `xticklabels=\empty` but neither work. Also, why is it showing repeated names (Doramus and Tidanme)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove the `xticklabels` you have to use `xticklabel=\empty` *after* `symbolic x coords={...}`.

[image]

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width  = 0.85*\textwidth,
    height = 8cm,
    major x tick style = transparent,
    ybar=2*\pgflinewidth,
    bar width=14pt,
    ymajorgrids = true,
    ylabel = {Percentage},
    xlabel = {},
    symbolic x coords={Doramus,Refaltido,Misanit,Fanatha,Sonphay,Laoli,Tidanme},
    scaled y ticks = false,
    xticklabel=\empty,% <- after symbolic x coords
    enlarge x limits=2,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=100,
    legend cell align=left,
    legend style={
            at={(.872,.5)},
            anchor=south,
            column sep=1ex
    }  
]
\addplot[style={green,fill=green}]
    coordinates {(Doramus,60)};
\addplot[style={orange,fill=orange}]
    coordinates {(Refaltido,17)};
\addplot[style={yellow,fill=yellow}]
    coordinates {(Misanit,6)};
\addplot[style={blue,fill=blue}]
    coordinates {(Fanatha,6)};
\addplot[style={purple,fill=purple}]
    coordinates {(Sonphay,5)};
\addplot[style={black,fill=black}]
    coordinates {(Laoli,4)};
\addplot[style={black,fill=white}]
    coordinates {(Tidanme,2)};
\legend{Doramus,Refaltido,Misanit,Fanatha,Sonphay,Laoli,Tidanme}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Or you can use `xtick=\empty` and remove `major x tick style=transparent` and `xticklabel=\empty`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width  = 0.85*\textwidth,
    height = 8cm,
    xtick=\empty,% <- added
    ybar=2*\pgflinewidth,
    bar width=14pt,
    ymajorgrids = true,
    ylabel = {Percentage},
    xlabel = {},
    symbolic x coords={Doramus,Refaltido,Misanit,Fanatha,Sonphay,Laoli,Tidanme},
    scaled y ticks = false,
    enlarge x limits=2,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=100,
    legend cell align=left,
    legend style={
            at={(.872,.5)},
            anchor=south,
            column sep=1ex
    }  
]
\addplot[style={green,fill=green}]
    coordinates {(Doramus,60)};
\addplot[style={orange,fill=orange}]
    coordinates {(Refaltido,17)};
\addplot[style={yellow,fill=yellow}]
    coordinates {(Misanit,6)};
\addplot[style={blue,fill=blue}]
    coordinates {(Fanatha,6)};
\addplot[style={purple,fill=purple}]
    coordinates {(Sonphay,5)};
\addplot[style={black,fill=black}]
    coordinates {(Laoli,4)};
\addplot[style={black,fill=white}]
    coordinates {(Tidanme,2)};
\legend{Doramus,Refaltido,Misanit,Fanatha,Sonphay,Laoli,Tidanme}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as above.

---

But note, if there are multiple bar plots in one axis the plots are shifted. So if you add `xticklabel style={rotate=90}` to the axis options you would get

[image]

If you do not want this shifts you can add

```
bar shift=0pt,
```

after `ybar` and decrease `enlargelimits` to for example `0.3`:

[image]

Then you can add

```
xtickmin=Doramus,
xtickmax=Tidanme,
```

to get

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width  = 0.85*\textwidth,
    height = 8cm,
    major x tick style = {draw=none},
    ybar=2*\pgflinewidth,
    bar shift=0pt,
    bar width=14pt,
    ymajorgrids = true,
    ylabel = {Percentage},
    xlabel = {},
    symbolic x coords={Doramus,Refaltido,Misanit,Fanatha,Sonphay,Laoli,Tidanme},
    xtickmin=Doramus,
    xtickmax=Tidanme,
    scaled y ticks = false,
    xticklabel style={rotate=90},
    enlarge x limits=.3,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=100,
    legend cell align=left,
    legend style={
            at={(.872,.5)},
            anchor=south,
            column sep=1ex
    }  
]
\addplot[style={green,fill=green}]
    coordinates {(Doramus,60)};
\addplot[style={orange,fill=orange}]
    coordinates {(Refaltido,17)};
\addplot[style={yellow,fill=yellow}]
    coordinates {(Misanit,6)};
\addplot[style={blue,fill=blue}]
    coordinates {(Fanatha,6)};
\addplot[style={purple,fill=purple}]
    coordinates {(Sonphay,5)};
\addplot[style={black,fill=black}]
    coordinates {(Laoli,4)};
\addplot[style={black,fill=white}]
    coordinates {(Tidanme,2)};
\legend{Doramus,Refaltido,Misanit,Fanatha,Sonphay,Laoli,Tidanme}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

To remove the xticklabels replace `major x tick style = {draw=none},` by `xtick=\empty,`. Then `xtickmin` and `xtickmax` can be removed.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a version that has no labels on the x axis. To your questions:

1. The duplicate labels come from the `enlarge x axis` part. If you remove it there are no duplicates.
2. The x labels can be deleted with `xtick=\empty`.

[image: graph]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width  = 0.85*\textwidth,
    height = 8cm,
    major x tick style = transparent,
    ybar=2*\pgflinewidth,
    bar width=14pt,
    ymajorgrids = true,
    ylabel = {Percentage},
    xlabel = {},
    symbolic x coords={Doramus,Refaltido,Misanit,Fanatha,Sonphay,Laoli,Tidanme},
    enlarge x limits=2,
    xticklabels=\empty,
    xtick=\empty,
    scaled y ticks = false,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=100,
    legend cell align=left,
    legend style={
            at={(.872,.5)},
            anchor=south,
            column sep=1ex
    }  
]

\addplot[style={green,fill=green}]
    coordinates {(Doramus,60)};
\addplot[style={orange,fill=orange}]
    coordinates {(Refaltido,17)};
\addplot[style={yellow,fill=yellow}]
    coordinates {(Misanit,6)};
\addplot[style={blue,fill=blue}]
    coordinates {(Fanatha,6)};
\addplot[style={purple,fill=purple}]
    coordinates {(Sonphay,5)};
\addplot[style={black,fill=black}]
    coordinates {(Laoli,4)};
\addplot[style={black,fill=white}]
    coordinates {(Tidanme,2)};
\legend{Doramus,Refaltido,Misanit,Fanatha,Sonphay,Laoli,Tidanme}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```